# "Thread safe" git pull or how to avoid ".../.git/index.lock': File exists."

Tags: git, jenkins-pipeline

Suppose I havbe two Jenkins builds that sometimes start together, if they both require the same git repository and try to pull together, one of them will fail with:

`fatal: Unable to create '/project_path/.git/index.lock': File exists.`

Is there a better way to go about it other than checking if "index.lock" exists?

Comment: Do these build share the same workspace directory? The `/project_path/` should help you finding out if this is a remote (git server) or a local (jenkins) error

Comment: Yes, they share the same workspace directory, and I don't really need both of the to pull. It's definitely a local error, and checking if the index.lock file exists and skipping the pull would work, just thought maybe there is a "proper" way to to it.

Comment: Your problem is deeper. Imagine one job pulls, and is running, while another job pulls again and changes the sources while the first job is still compiling. you will need some kind of locking through the whole job - or separate directories which is the default in jenkins

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [Daniel Alder notes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55448359/thread-safe-git-pull-or-how-to-avoid-git-index-lock-file-exists#comment97627454_55448359), papering over this particular error leaves you with a deeper, more malignant error.

While `git pull` is not specifically the problem, this is another symptom of the *kind* of problem that arises from using `git pull`.  If you avoid `git pull`, by replacing every `git pull` with the two Git commands that Git `git pull` runs, the problem *may* be more obvious (or maybe will just move into the second Git command ):

```
git fetch && git merge
```

or:

```
git fetch && git rebase
```

(but don't do this either!).

The problem, which I hope is now obvious but maybe is just hidden inside the second half of the `&&` here, is that `git merge` or `git rebase` will *modify the work-tree*.  If you have some command(s) working *in* the work-tree *while* you modify the work-tree, those commands will see inconsistent sets of files.

Suppose, for instance, that `git merge` or `git rebase` will modify both `main.py` and `routine.py`.  It might modify `main.py` first, and just at that moment, a Python interpreter will load up and use the updated `main.py` that needs new code from `routine.py`, but Git itself has not yet gotten around to updating `routine.py`.

The usual way to avoid this problem is to be sure that the work-tree is up to date *before* starting any operations, whether those are Jenkins jobs, stages within a single Jenkins job, or just anything you intend to run yourself.  Once the work-tree *is* up to date, you never need to `git pull`, because it's up to date.

If you want to have a Jenkins job run particular Git commands, that job probably needs to have its own private work-tree.  A private work-tree, whether it's the main work-tree of a separate repository or just an added work-tree of a shared repository, has its own HEAD and index, and therefore a private `index.lock` as well.